# Trying to call a (void) method from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to call a (void) method from another class, the class is ViewController.h & .m in the ViewController.h file I have;

```
-(void)showMore;
```

and in the ViewController.m file I have

```
-(void)showMore {

    //my stuff to show in here
}
```

I am calling it from a BoothViewController using this method;

```
ViewController *app = (ViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] init];
        [app showMore];
```

It does not show any errors in code, however it crashes during testing with an unrecognised selector.

I also tried with no success;

```
ViewController *app = (ViewController *) [ViewController init];
        [app showMore];
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to allocate and init your view controller before sending messages to it:

```
ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[myViewController showMore];
```

Or if the View controller is the app rootViewController:

```
ViewController *myViewController = (ViewController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
[myViewController showMore];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `alloc` your controller first :

```
ViewController *app = (ViewController *) [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

You cannot just `init` something.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[[ViewController alloc] init] showMore];`

Answer (score 0):

you    import the ViewController Class in .h file of your view

```
#import "ViewController"
@interface YourClass: UIViewController
{
    ViewController *appView;
}

@Property(nonatomic, retain)ViewController *appView;

@end
```

Then .m Class do it like this to allocate it

```
-(void)someMethod 
{
    self.appView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.appView showMore];
}
```

Here is All to call the method from another class hope it will work for you as it done for me

Comment: What's with the ivar and the property? If you have the property the ivar is created automatically for you so no need to include the ivar