# Call method from each view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to call this method from each view controller.But I do not know where this method will write and how i can call this method.

```
-(void)playSound{

NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
[audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: declare in appdelegate file

Comment: can you provide the example

Comment: Create a separate NSObject Class and paste this method . And call it where ever you want

Comment: Check this link  --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/23269540/4970453

Comment: You can't just plonk this method anywhere, as it has a dependancy - (audioPlayer is declared outside the scope and also is assigned its delegate property). One way is to wrap it all up (audioPlayer included) in a singleton object and import the singleton.h in any class that wants to play a sound.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one `BaseViewController` and declare this method inside `BaseViewController.h` and implement inside `BaseViewController.m` file, than set  all your `ViewController` as a child of `BaseViewController`.

**BaseViewController.h**

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

-(void)playSound;

@end
```

**BaseViewController.m**

```
@interface BaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

-(void)playSound {
     NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
     NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
     audioPlayer.delegate = self;
     [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
     [audioPlayer play];
}
@end
```

Now in your **viewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : BaseViewController

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self playSound];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a category:

```
@interface UIViewController (UIViewControllerAudio)

-(void)playSound;

@end


@implementation UIViewController (UIViewControllerAudio)

- (void)playSound{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

and the you can call in your view controller:

```
[self playSound];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

create the one BaseViewController

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

 - (void) playSound;

 @end
```

**Step-2**

on that *BaseViewController.m*

```
@implementation BaseViewController

-(void)playSound{

NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
[audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

**Step-3**

```
  #import "BaseViewController.h"

// Notice this class is a subclass of BaseViewController (parent)
@interface yourViewController : BaseViewController
@end
```

**step -4**

you can call directly

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 [self playSound];
}
```